# Converting list of list into 2 independent lists

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists that looks like this:

```
lol=[['"buy":17'], ['"hold":18'], ['"sell":3']]
```

Is there any simple way to convert the list of lists into 2 independent lists like this?:

```
list1=["buy","hold","sell"]
list2=[17,18,3]
```

First I tried a replace over the list:

```
lol.replace('[','').replace(']','')
```

But outputed that  `'list' object has no attribute 'replace'`

Then I thought I could use regular expressions over the `lol` to at least obtaining the numbers in an independent list with the following code:

```
re.findall('\d{1,2}',lol.string)
```

but returned outputed that it `expected string or bytes-like object`

Comment: `zip(*[[s.strip('"') for s in L[0].split(":")] for L in lol])`

Comment: Read [ask] along with [mcve]

Comment: @inspectorG4dget That does not produce integers from the strings.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye: fair point. This should fix it: `zip(*[[s.strip('"'), int(n)] for s,n in map(lambda L: L[0].split(":"), lol)])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split the strings on `':'` and then use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to produce the final output:

```
import ast

l1, l2 = zip(*[map(ast.literal_eval, lst[0].split(':')) for lst in lol])
print(l1, l2)
# ('buy', 'hold', 'sell'), (17, 18, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this. Not sure if it is the best way though.

```
lol=[['"buy":17'], ['"hold":18'], ['"sell":3']]
list1 = list()
list2 = list()
for list_ in lol:
    list1.append(list_[0].split(':')[0])
    list2.append(list_[0].split(':')[1])
```

Output:

```
list1
Out[59]: ['"buy"', '"hold"', '"sell"']

list2
Out[60]: ['17', '18', '3']
```